# How to discover API endpoints without submitting a form?

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

I'm trying to dig myself into software engineering and API endpoints. I've discovered that API endpoints can be fetched on multiple ways by sending forms and such. But how to discover endpoints when its just a blank list of raw data such as:

https://dm.watch/api/mixedlist.json

Their code is open source and I've tried to figure it out but I can't, reason why I am here.

In the Github code below they are retrieving (atleast I think) some information of this list:

https://github.com/DMWatch/DMWatch/blob/main/src/main/java/com/DMWatch/CaseManager.java

Is there any way how to make any GET/PUT/DELETE calls to this API? If so, how?

Thank you.

I've tried to send GET requests of specific objects with Postman but all it is returning is the entire list.